# bitwise left shift different results for identical operands

Tags: python, numpy, bit-shift

Consider the array

```
a = np.array([64,  8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 56, 64])
```

Its first and last elements are identical

```
a[0] == a[-1]
# True
```

Now let's left shift by `a`

```
b = 1<<a
```

And compare the first and last elements

```
b[0] == b[-1]
# False
```

What the heck is going on here?

Can anyone reproduce this? Is this a bug?

The **actual values** are

```
b
# array([                0,               256,             65536,
#                 16777216,        4294967296,     1099511627776,
#          281474976710656, 72057594037927936,                 1])
```

`numpy` version is 1.17.0 on `Python` 3.6.5

**Expected Values**

Either value has its logic: 0 = 1 * 2^64 mod 2^64 and 1 = 1 * 2^(64 mod 64)

**Related**

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10299

Comment: What values are you getting for `b`? I tried this on the python.org website and it worked fine.

Comment: For reference and understanding, what is the expected value?

Comment: @DanielAaron I would expect 0, but not 100% sure. In any case I would expect the same value for repeat evaluations.

Comment: it is actually 1, this appears to be a bug, not sure on what end.  I used python 3.7.3 and Numpy 1.17.2

Comment: @DanielAaron Are you sure of that? What is the logic?

Answer (score 1):

For me its showing true: 
python 3.7.4
numpy 1.17.x

```py
import numpy
 a = numpy.array([10,20,15,10])
 a[0]==a[-1]
True
 b = 1<<a
 b[0] == b[-1]
True

```

Comment: can you get specific version? 
    import numpy
    numpy.version.version

Comment: yeah its 1.17.2

Comment: Could you please try the exact same `a` as in OP?

Comment: I added expected results to question @PaulPanzer

Comment: if you remove any element and make the no of element equal or less than `8` then its showing `True` again

Comment: @DanielAaron It's not what I would expect. Accorfing to the docs: _Bits are shifted to the left by appending x2 0s at the right of x1. Since the internal representation of numbers is in binary format, this operation is equivalent to multiplying x1 by 2**x2._

Comment: @PaulPanzer you are correct!  `64 = '0100 0000'` so the value should be 0, I assumed my python & numpy was right ;)  so this is showing different behavior in my versions, yet is still equally wrong :P

Comment: @DanielAaron apparently 1 is the behavior of the intel machine instruction: the shift value is truncated at 6 bits so 64 becomes 0 meaning no change.